# excel formula for search from one column and insert data at 3rd column

Tags: database, excel

Say in excel
Column 1   2  3
Name   phone  blank
Now i want to search from column 1 st name of person and then want to insert in column 3rd no. Changed 
suggest excel formula for this

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking!

Answer (score 0):

I agree question is very far from clear, but suspect this may be what is required;

```
=IF(INDEX(C[-1],MATCH(RC[-2],R1C[-2]:RC[-2],0))=RC[-1],"","Changed")
```